# Accessing ScalaFX chart axis extreme values

Tags: scala, charts, scalafx

I'm building a regression visualiser and can plot the original data and calculate the regression model. For fitting, I'd like to include predictions for the whole chart axis range available, not only the original data range.

Creating the empty chart sets xAxis 0 to 110 by default.

[image: Creating the chart]

Then I'm plotting the data:
[image]

How can I access the visible xAxis extreme values, and especially the upper 5.5?

Trying `xAxis.getUpperBound` gives the original 110.

Comment: See discussion on ScalaFX: https://github.com/scalafx/scalafx/discussions/338

Comment: Thank you. The problem actually was that the value didn't have time enough to be updated before my next command. The try of xAxis.getUpperBound was correct.